# The same graphic but two devices according to screenfetch

Tags: drivers, kernel, graphics, kubuntu, amd-graphics

In the near past on Kubuntu 18.04 my graphic card was defined as **AMD/ATI Thames Radeon 7500M/7600M**, but now it is defined as **AMD TURKS (DRM 2.50.0 / 4.15.0-70-generic, LLVM 8.0.0)** with the latest Kernel.

What do this mean? Does it becomes faulty (My graphic adapter)? Which of them is the best? I need an explanation.

``````
./+o+-       saidbakr@Satellite-L850-A700
                  yyyyy- -yyyyyy+      OS: Ubuntu 18.04 bionic
               ://+//////-yyyyyyo      Kernel: x86_64 Linux 4.15.0-70-generic
           .++ .:/++++++/-.+sss/`      Uptime: 2h 9m
         .:++o:  /++++++++/:--:/-      Packages: 3420
        o:+o+:++.`..```.-/oo+++++/     Shell: bash 4.4.20
       .:+o:+o/.          `+sssoo+/    Resolution: 1440x900
  .++/+:+oo+o:`             /sssooo.   DE: KDE 5.47.0 / Plasma 5.12.9
 /+++//+:`oo+o               /::--:.   WM: KWin
 \+/+o+++`o++o               ++////.   WM Theme: Materia Manjaro Dark
  .++.o+++oo+:`             /dddhhh.   GTK Theme: Layan-dark [GTK2/3]
       .+.o+oo:.          `oddhhhh+    Icon Theme: Tela-dark
        \+.++o+o``-````.:ohdhhhhh+     Font: Noto Sans Regular
         `:o+++ `ohhhhhhhhyo++os:      CPU: Intel Core i5-2450M @ 4x 3.1GHz [58.0°C]
           .o:`.syhhhhhhh/.oo++o`      GPU: AMD TURKS (DRM 2.50.0 / 4.15.0-70-generic, LLVM 8.0.0)
               /osyyyyyyo++ooo+++/     RAM: 2259MiB / 7936MiB
                   ````` +oo+++o\:    
                          `oo++.
``````

[image]

Comment: The old screenshot is not from Ubuntu.

Comment: Yes, it is Elementary OS which is based on Ubuntu with almost the same old Kernel @OrganicMarble

Comment: compare the output from `dpkg -l | grep mesa` on both system. Also from `lsmod | egrep 'radeon|amd'`